# okhttp3 Null Respone uploading file

Tags: php, android, okhttp

Hi I am trying to upload a jpg file using okhttp3's multipart request to a php server. The script checks for `$_FILES["image1"]` and works correctly from html form. When using the below code I get a null response from server.

If I remove the last `addFormDataPart` that contains the file upload part, I get a response from server that image1 is not set.

**Edit*** I have found that `boolean b = files.get(0).isFile();` returns false for files stored on my mobile device and true for those on dropbox. Dropbox files return correct response file on phone still return null http response.

Any suggestions?

```
public AsyncHttpPost(String id, String password, List<File> files, OnTaskComplete listener ) {
    MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPG = MediaType.parse("image/jpg");
    MultipartBody.Builder  builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart(ResponseDTO.TAG_ID, String.valueOf(id))
            .addFormDataPart(ResponseDTO.TAG_PASSWORD, password)
            .addFormDataPart("image1", "Test.jpg", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, files.get(0)));

    mRequestBody = builder.build();
    mListener = listener;
}

public AsyncHttpPost() {
}

public void setListener(OnTaskComplete listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String result = "";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(params[0])
            .post(mRequestBody)
            .build();

    Response response  = null;
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (response != null) {
            result = response.body().string();
        } else {
            result = "null";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using the URI path isFile() returned false. So I had to create file using path as below. This then lead to a null response after a few seconds so i also updated timeout values for my http client

```
File f = new File(uri.getPath()); //didnt work
File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Test.jpg");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```